# Excluding double pageviews in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How can I filter double pageviews in Google Analytics reports? We''ve got GA code pasted twice and now we have unclear data. Any ideas?

Comment: Can I take a look at your code and result to see the problem coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter historical data that are consolidated in Analytics. If you have submitted 2 pageviews for it means you have seen 2 pages.

Comment: But there are the same pageviews for the same user in the same second. It's not a normal situation. Moreover, as I explained we had a doubled GA code on the page. I've got an answer on one forum that is possible in Data Studio.

Comment: I am aware that this is not a normal situation but the consolidated data in analytics can no longer be modified. Probably something can be done in the data studio, such as exporting them in an excel and processing them, but this does not mean cleaning up the situation in analytics with a filter. For example, you would have to recalculate manually the bounce rate, even the time per page or the duration of the session and other metrics... it is not enough to remove only the double page.